# Create an enumeration of URLs - Error: Identifer expected

Tags: c#, asp.net, enums

Shamed by this simple question. For some reason, I want to put all asp.net URLs in an enum. But I got an error: `identifer expected`

My code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;

namespace Admin.Code
{
    public enum url
    {
       /_layouts/Admin/test1.aspx,
       /_layouts/Admin/test2.aspx,
       /_layouts/Admin/test3.aspx
    }

    class AdminUrlSettings
    {
    }
}
```

Thanks.

Comment: Please don't try that. Put them into a List<string> please.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Identifiers in C# can't contain `/` characters.  They are limited to underscores, letters and numbers (and possibly a `@` prefix).  To fix this you need to make the enum values valid C# identifiers

```
enum url {
  test1,
  test2,
  test3
}
```

Later turning these into an actual valid url can be done with a switch statement over the value

```
public static string GetRelativeUrl(url u) {
  switch (u) {
    case url.test1:
      return "/_layouts/Admin/test1.aspx";
    case url.test2:
      return "/_layouts/Admin/test2.aspx";
    case url.test3:
      return "/_layouts/Admin/test3.aspx";
    default: 
      // Handle bad URL, possibly throw
      throw new Exception();
  }
}
```

Comment: @Love sure, you could create a property which just did the equivalent of the above method

Answer (score 3):

Here's something I've done many times to turn enumerated values into "friendly strings". You can also use it to create "string-valued" enums. It's in the same vein as Msonic's solution, but the attribute is built into the Framework.

```
public enum url
{
   [Description(@"/_layouts/Admin/test1.aspx")] Test1,
   [Description(@"/_layouts/Admin/test2.aspx")] Test2,
   [Description(@"/_layouts/Admin/test2.aspx")] Test3
}

...

public static string GetDescription(this Enum enumValue)
{
    object[] attr = enumValue.GetType().GetField(enumValue.ToString())
            .GetCustomAttributes(typeof (DescriptionAttribute), false);
        if (attr.Length > 0)
            return ((DescriptionAttribute) attr[0]).Description;

        return enumValue.ToString();
}

//usage
Response.Redirect(url.Test1.GetDescription());
```

Answer (score 2):

These aren't valid enum identifiers. You'll need string enumerations. Here's an [example](http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/11130/String-Enumerations-in-C)

You will be able to do something like this:

```
public enum url
{
    [StringValue("/_layouts/Admin/test1.aspx")]
    Test1,
    [StringValue("/_layouts/Admin/test2.aspx")]
    Test2,
    [StringValue("/_layouts/Admin/test3.aspx")]
    Test3
}
```

Comment: StringValueAttribute isn't built-in, but you can do exactly the same thing with DescriptionAttributes.

Comment: Much more info on the example page provided. This helped me find a good solution, thanks

Answer (score 0):

Enums don't really work like that. Valid identifiers work the same way variable names do (ie. a combination of letters, numbers and underscores not beginning with a number). Why not just use a list:

```
List<string> urls = new List<string>{"/_layouts/Admin/test1.aspx", "/_layouts/Admin/test2.aspx", "/_layouts/Admin/test3.aspx"}
```

or use slightly different identifiers:

```
public enum url
{
     layout_Admin_test1,
     layout_Admin_test2,
     layout_Admin_test3
}
```

Comment: Remove please the "[etc.]", it will confuse the OP